# How can I make my grid full height instead of it shrinking some items?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have 8 items in my grid; items 1 and 8 are the header and footer respectively, and items 2-7 are parts of the main body.

Items 2-7 are in a two-column format. The problem I am encountering is that when I expand the height of my header (item 1) the rest of the items shrink accordingly; I am stuck and would love some help. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  justify-items: stretch;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item4 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.item5 {
  background-color: black;
}

.item6 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.item7 {
  background-color: brown;
}

.item8 {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">A</div>
  <div class="item2">B</div>
  <div class="item3">C</div>
  <div class="item4">D</div>
  <div class="item5">E</div>
  <div class="item6">F</div>
  <div class="item7">G</div>
  <div class="item8">H</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You obviously have to stick to the old school rules. If you don't know what you want to achieve, you will have no idea how to develop the solution. Please try to explain your problem and maybe I can help you.

Comment: You have five rows, but you define the `grid-template-rows: 50% 50%`? What end result do you want? Please: have a read of the "*[ask]*" guidelines and take the [tour] to help you understand what we need from you in your question in order to help you.

Comment: Go to https://jsfiddle.net/baeyrd4s/ and check if this satisfies your need. I have added overflow-y: auto; in case one of the columns has longer text than the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*removed the `html` tag, updated the styling to the `body` and `.container`*

```
body {
    max-width: 100vw;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
    grid-template-rows: 81% 50% 30% auto 30%;
    justify-items: stretch;
}
```

The original code only defined the first 2 rows' height, I put in some random values for the other rows. `auto` also works to define row height

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm sorry if my question was a bit complicated, I'm only starting to learn this and grid has been rough for me. This is exactly what I wanted. Again, thanks!